# C# I'm getting a FileNotFound Exception when using StreamReader to read a text file inside resources

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
using (SteamReader sr = new StreamReader("text.txt"))
```

I also tried to don't put the text file on the `.resx` file.

Answer (score 4):

The `StreamReader` constructor that you are using expects the file to exist on the disk. If the file is embedded inside your assembly you could use the [`GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx) method.

For example:

```
// Get the current assembly. If the file is embedded inside a different
// assembly you will need to get that assembly
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("AssemblyName.test.txt"))
using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    ...
}
```

The key under which the resource is embedded into your assembly will depend on where is the file situated in the hierarchy. It is always prefixed with the assembly name and then any possible subfolders if you have some.

Make sure that the `Build Action` is set to `Embedded Resource` for this file in its properties. And here's [`an article`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) with more details about accessing embedded resources.

Comment: If you are having trouble getting the Fully Qualified name for the resource, see this article for using ILDASM to find it (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114997/Embedding-and-Using-Resources-from-Net-Assembly).