# I get FileNotFound exception when StreamReader tryes to read a txt file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, io, streamreader

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("gold.txt"))
        {

            text.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Why I'm getting this error? I simply created the text file and tryed to make a new StreamReader to read gold.txt.

Comment: what is the working path of the application? what is the application's current directory? (not necessarily the same thing) and where (relative to the application) is "gold.txt"? have you tried using a full file path? what user account is the application using? does it have access to the file? if "gold.txt" is in your VS project, is it set to deploy with the application?

Comment: How different is this issue to your other recent question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923652/c-sharp-im-getting-a-filenotfound-exception-when-using-streamreader-to-read-a-t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have "gold.txt" in your project in visual studio, make sure that the property "Copy to Output Directory" is set to "Copy if newer" or "Copy always".

Hope this helps. I have failed on this point many, many times :P

Also, it is always a good idea to check if File.Exists("gold.txt") before reading. I also tend to use File.OpenText or similar, as I feel it make sit more obvious that you are working with a file.

Remember to Close();

Comment: Thank you. You helped me so much. I've been stuck with this problem for weeks. Thank you so much...

Answer (score 1):

When you give `StreamReader` a non-qualified path as a parameter it will look for the file in the application's working directory. If the file isn't located there, you'd probably want to give it a fully qualified path, for example:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Path\To\gold.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because the system cannot find the file based on the path you have passed to the StreamReader. This is probably because the file is not in the directory that the application is looking by default.

As already suggested using the full path, or putting the file in the right location should solve the problem in the short term. However, at some point you'll probably want to ask the user to locate the file like this:

```
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                text.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```